# Apache authentication - Exclude paths from <Directory> defined authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, ntlm

I currently use the following directives to apply NTLM authentication to our Drupal installation, but I need to exclude some paths. I've tried adding  directives for the specific paths I want to exclude, but they still require auth.

How would I go about changing it so the authentication is done on all the site, apart from a specified list of sub uri's. E.G. /nodejs/message, /wiki-auth. As you can see below, I've unsuccessfully tried to add some directives in that allow any access to /nodejs/message

```
<Directory "/srv/##/public_html">
    AuthName "NTLM Authentication thingy"
    NTLMAuth on
    NTLMAuthHelper "/usr/bin/ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmss$
    NTLMBasicAuthoritative on
    AuthType NTLM
    require valid-user
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName ##
 DocumentRoot /srv/##/public_html
 ErrorLog /srv/##/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /srv/##/logs/access.log combined
 LogLevel warn

 <Location "/server-status">
   SetHandler server-status
   Satisfy any
   AuthType None
   Require all granted
   Deny from all
   Allow from ####
 </Location>

 <Location "/nodejs/message">
   Satisfy any
   AuthType None
   Allow from all
 </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```